# SharePoint 2013 Calendar Reservation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

My company moves to Sharepoint 2013 and wants to have a reservation calendar. 
But the feature called resource reservation not enable in 2013, just in 2010 based on 'Group Work Site'. 
I can make it using Javascript, but i prefer a natively solution, if it possible.
Can i make it natively?

New question:

The events show up in the All Items list view, but I cannot figure out how to get them to appear on the calendar. Is there a step I am missing, or something else that needs to be done to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Changes from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742%28v=office.15%29.aspx#section1) `Group Work site template and Group Work solution Description` has been deprecated in SharePoint 2013.

### Solution

Develop sandbox solution that enables hidden 'Group Work Lists' feature and adds calendar with resource reservation and member scheduling features as described  in article [Reservation of resources in SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2013 Online in Office 365](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/588685/ReservationplusofplusresourcesplusinplusSharePoint)